# Amazon EC2 payment transparency, breaking the free usage tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I was attracted by the AWS free tier to give EC2/S3 a try. However, one thing I'm worried about is the payment process. There's quite a few management menus and it doesn't seem entirely transparent when I would break the free usage tier (or if I decide to pay, when I break that usage tier).

You can download .csv usage reports, but I wish the billing/usage monitoring was a little more interactive so I don't get unpleasantly surprised. Does anyone have experiences EC2, is there some aspect of the management interface that makes this a easier/less worrisome?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can monitor your AWS resource usage and the resulting fees here:

> AWS Account Activity
>   https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/

You can see how current the report is at the top.  In my experience it lags by a few hours, which is pretty amazing if you think of how many different customers AWS has and how many little things they have to keep track of to calculate your fees (e.g., every disk I/O request and network byte sent).

Click "Expand All Services" to see the usage/fees broken down even more.

Note: You don't "decide to pay".  You already gave AWS your credit card and agreed to pay according to their fee structure.  If your resource usage goes over the free tier, AWS will automatically charge your credit card at the end of the month.  Monitor the above page regularly to make sure your charges are accumulating as expected.

Comment: I see... so my worries about a stray job/forgetting to shutdown/accidentally starting the wrong type of instance knocking me out of the free tier into a bill payment are warranted. Guess I'll just have to be careful.

Comment: My approach was to use a virtual credit card number and set a low monthly limit. Citi, Bank of America, and FIA (and others, I'm sure) offer this as an option.

Comment: lid: Amazon charges your credit card at the end of the month for all of your resource usage during the month.  You will be responsible for the total amount you used in the month.  Just because your credit card will deny the charge doesn't mean that you don't owe Amazon for what you used and agreed to pay for.

Comment: If you are going to dispute something with a large company, its best to have the money on your side. There is no way I would put a CC with a $40,000 limit on an account that should be about $10 per month. Amazon knows that this is a huge problem (although actual occurrences are really rare). They are negligent IMHO for not having some sort of settable cap on monthly spending.

Comment: Tom Anderson: What would you like Amazon to do with your servers and data when you reach the spending limit?

Comment: AWS supports billing alerts now, so you can set one up for your personal limit and then take whatever action you seem appropriate.

Comment: As I understand how it functions billing alerts are not enough. It still doesn't protect me from a DDOS attack that can burn few thousands $ from my CC. Or a link to my blog post on HN or a bug in my app or... If Amazon is capable to record every request that goes to my virtual instance there should be no problem of calculating the current spending. Azure implemented spending limit. Amazon can't ? All users want is to have some security there will not be very bad news when the bill comes.

Comment: IMO the AWS pricing is freaking mess for those wishing to just try it. Lot's of figuring out how to just try the free tier, and when is billing involved.

Comment: Yep, I was pretty sure I was using everything within the free tier, then they sent me a bill. I shut down my instances. Not going to use it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use AWS Billing Alerts to notify when you exceeds the fee tier,

If you currently use the AWS Free Tier, you can set a billing alert to notify you if you exceed the free tier by setting a threshold of $0.00.

refer to,

[AWS Billing Alerts](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account?ie=UTF8&ie=UTF8&action=billing-alerts)